# Input file is not working in facebook's internal browser, any solutions?

Tags: android, facebook, file, input, webview

My external link uses a file upload input but I can´t make it work because it seems to not being supported by facebook's basic internal browser/WebView on android phones. I've searched for and answer but found nothing related to facebook, any solutions anyone?

Comment: Have a look on how you can add file chooser in webview for files uploading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687282/webviewclient-and-filechooser

Comment: thank you, the thing is I am working on facebook's app plataform so don't have a way of manipulating the in-app webview behavior.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing on the in-app browser with the file upload button?

Comment: when you click it nothing happens, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe is not the exact case but I fixed this issue with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705145/3182171

Answer (score 1):

In fact the problem is that Android webview does not have a default implementation for showing a file chooser. And each App that use a webview must implement some function of the WebChromeClient to support input of type file.

So unless Android webview will have a default file chooser implementation, The only solution would be that Facebook Android dev team implement the method

```
onShowFileChooser
```

of the WebChromeClient. See android webview documentation:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri[]%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams%29)

But the problem is how to report this problem to Facebook Android dev team.